# Regex matching everything until you dont need a comma at end of line

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex problem where I want to match everything until I dont see a comma at the end. In the example here I want to capture Josh,Mike and Richard.

Current regex:

Additional [nN]ames[^:\n\r]*:\s*([,\sa-zA-Z0-9:/_-]+)\Rrandom

However, I cant rely on the random words section being there so my proposed solution is to have some sort of way for the regex to capture until it doesnt see a comma at the end of the line or something of that sort, but still capture the words until that point. In this example, it would stop at Richard because it doesnt see a comma at the end of line but still captures Richard. Solution would be helpful!!

Example:

Additional Names:Josh,

Mike,

Richard

random wordsa asdoajdioaj : 320

Comment: Everything with a comma at the end is acceptable?

Comment: Richard doesn't have comma you are capturing that as well?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to capture up until Richard, so Josh,Mike,Richard. Essentially everything in Additional names until there is not comma at the end

Comment: Is single `Josh` acceptable?

Comment: No I need to parse everything in Additional names section so Josh,Mike, and Richard

Comment: Please check my answer posted below that matches the case you presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can be a single name after `Additional Names:` or multiple followed by a comma:

```
Additional [nN]ames[^:\n\r]*:\s*([\w-:/]+(?:\s*,\s*[\w-:/]+)*)\s+
```

The pattern matches:

- `Additional [nN]ames` Match literally
- `[^:\n\r]*:` Match optional repetitions of any char excluding newlines and `:` and then match the `:`
- `\s*` Match optional whitspace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[\w-:/]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters in the character class
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\s*,\s*` match a comma between optional whitespace chars
    - `[\w-:/]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters in the character class
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwmg1K/1).

In Java with the doubled backslashes:

```
String regex = "Additional [nN]ames[^:\\n\\r]*:\\s*([\\w-:/]+(?:\\s*,\\s*[\\w-:/]+)*)\\s+";
```

Comment: How would you handle an edge case like thishttps://regex101.com/r/mNFz4c/1

Comment: @user20066926 Like this? https://regex101.com/r/DaAY2R/1

Comment: Thanks so much im only messing up on two edge cases now if you could help with that.It shouldnt be able to parse if there is not a new line character https://regex101.com/r/t8HsvF/1. and also it should parse if there is an invalid character like "&" https://regex101.com/r/TZ5amS/1. So it shouldnt match with Jack at all in that example

Comment: @user20066926 Can you create a regex101 demo link with examples that should and should not match? It is not clear to me what should have a newline and what you match  with "invalid characters"

Comment: Here i have outlined an example of what matches and what does not. https://regex101.com/r/E5m6mB/1. I think all of the "should matches", you have correct, essentially spaces and stuff does not matter but there should be a new line when you are finished with everything. As outlined in the "should not" match, you need a new line in order for it to match and invalid characters like "&" should not even create a match. BTW sorry for your troubles ill buy you a coffee for this lol

Comment: @user20066926 Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/GxMva2/1

Comment: Thanks so much i think it works!! Just curious can you go over how the non capture group works, specifically this (?:\s*,\s*[\w-:\/]+)

Comment: @user20066926 I have updated the answer with a breakdown of the pattern. The non capture group is used to repeat the whole part what is specified in the group.

Comment: Hello, I thought it was resolved but there was one edge case i didnt think of, https://regex101.com/r/nyUOJb/1. Do you have a fix if they dont add additional names

Comment: @user20066926 Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/4fxiXF/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7haf4S/1 Some of the old things are failing, one in should match and one in should not match. (Should not match if there is not a new line and should match regardless of additional spaces)

Comment: @user20066926 So it should not end with a dangling colon? https://regex101.com/r/G3mKlZ/1

Comment: It can, It can be Additional Names: \n Random Field:asdsad. Essentially the Additional Names field can be empty but should not be picking up the Random Field section. In the new one you sent, some of the "should not" matches are still matching. Like It has to end with newline character

Comment: @user20066926 As you have altered the question, can you please create a regex101 example with what should and should not be matched?

Comment: sorry for the miscommunication. But the regex examples we were working on before it still valid https://regex101.com/r/ErOGql/1. However, as you can see, two of the "should not matches" are now matching

Comment: @user20066926 I Java you can match optional horizontal whitespace chars and then match a newline https://regex101.com/r/nTsD9n/1